# Macro Argument Pairs

Tags: c++, c, macros

I'm trying to do some macro magic with class generation where the classes actually reflect SQL records to reduce boilerplate and hard coded strings.  In the macro, I want to have pairs of arguments where one is the field name and the second is the corresponding C++ data type.  For example:

```
ID (GUID) | Name (std::string) |
```

At the moment, I have to have a separate macro for each item:

```
DataRecordGetSetField(ID, GUID)
DataRecordGetSetField(Name, std::string)
```

Due to some extensions that my manager wants, like whether the field is required, I need to be able to place them in the same macro and then parse out each:

```
DataRecord((ID, GUID), (Name, std::string))
```

In this example, how would I get the type of the ID field (GUID) or is this even possible?  Mind you, this is just an example and I could have any number of fields.  I had hoped to do this with variadic macros, but, in the end, I guess I might just have to have a bunch of macros depending on how many fields I have?

I'm not great with macros, so please go easy on me!

Thanks!

Comment: variadic macros have been supported by the C preprocessor since C99 - that *is* more than 1½ decades old now!

Comment: @harper: Variadic macros have been part of C since C99 and C++ since C++11. However, there is no easy way to loop or recurse over them. (You could do it boost-preprocessor-library style by counting the arguments and concatenating the count to produce a non-variadic macro.)

Comment: There has to be a way to do it with the boost preprocessor library (up to some limit like 10 or 20 columns.  The trouble is that I'm damned if I can find it - the library is a triumph of ingenuity, but the documentation is awful.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thank for recommending boost.  I actually had no idea they had a preproccessor library. It's so big now that I have a hard time keeping track of what it has!

Comment: The preprocessor library is one of their oldest actually - you can see that in the way the docs are so unlike the rest of the boost docs.